# Disable or hide seekbar in MediaStyle notifications

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-notifications

Trying to build a live stream media playback app, the media style notifications in 28 and below sdk looks good without any seekbar, but when running same application in Android 10 (SDK 29) the notification is showing additional seekbar which i don't want since the stream is live and i am using default exoplayer (exo vers. 2.10.8) behavior to cache.

How do i disable or hide the seekbar?

tried setting below in notification builder:

.setProgress(0,0,true)

Snippet of notification below :

```
    Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this,Constant.CHANNEL_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_logo)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setLargeIcon(artwork)
            .addAction(new Notification.Action.Builder(
                    Icon.createWithResource(getApplicationContext(),playPauseResourceId),
                    "Play/Pause",
                    playPausePendingIntent).build())
            .addAction(new Notification.Action.Builder(
                    Icon.createWithResource(getApplicationContext(),R.drawable.exo_icon_stop),
                    "Play/Pause",
                    stopPendingIntent).build())
            .setStyle(new Notification.MediaStyle().setShowActionsInCompactView(0).setMediaSession(mediaSession.getSessionToken()))
            .setSubText(subText)
            .setContentIntent(pendingActivityIntent)
            .setVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
            .setProgress(0,0,true)
            .build();
```

Screeshot :

[image]

Comment: Which version of ExoPlayer do you use?

Comment: @Squti version 2.10.8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `PlayerNotificationManager` instead of `Notification.Builder` and pass custom `Bundle` extra to `MediaDescriptionCompat.Builder` using `setExtras()` method with  `MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_DURATION` key and `-1` value then override `getMediaDescription()` method of `TimelineQueueNavigator` class and pass it to `MediaSessionConnector` like so :

```
mediaSessionConnector.setQueueNavigator(new TimelineQueueNavigator(mediaSession) {
    @Override
    public MediaDescriptionCompat getMediaDescription(Player player, int windowIndex) {
        Bundle extras = new Bundle();
        extras.putInt(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_DURATION, -1);

        return new MediaDescriptionCompat.Builder()
                .setMediaId(trackModel.mediaId)
                .setIconBitmap(trackModel.bitmap)
                .setTitle(trackModel.title)
                .setDescription(trackModel.description)
                .setExtras(extras)
                .build();
    }
});
```

Comment: i am using Notification.Builder to build notifications not MediaDescriptionCompat, tried putting the extras in notif builder no changes at all, seeker still shows up.

Comment: You need to use PlayerNotificationManager class in ExoPlayer @Manti_Core

Comment: going this way will cost me more restructuring, already written so much for notifications customizing in my code.There should be some way around for media style notifications too.

Comment: PlayerNotificationManager requires MessionSessionCompat, but i am using MediaSession

Comment: This link is a complete implementation of music player by ExoPlayer using PlayerNotificationManager and TimelineQueueNavigator https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/tree/io18/audio-app

Comment: unable to get this particular import - com.google.android.exoplayer2.ext.mediasession.MediaSessionConnector
using - implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.10.8'

Comment: Try this     implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:extension-mediasession:2.10.8'
@Manti_Core

Comment: This solution worked, but on the contrary had to use compat classes to compensate for this. Also now i have to work on customizing the notification again, there are additional actions on the notifications that i dont need, all i need is play/pause and stop button.

Answer (score 9):

I also encountered this problem, but I am using NotificationCompat instead of exoplayer.
I followed Squti's answer and found the solution to hide the seek bar for NotificationCompat.

```
val mediaSession = MediaSessionCompat(context, "your tag")

//These two lines work
val mediaMetadata = MediaMetadata.Builder().putLong(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_DURATION, -1L).build()
mediaSession.setMetadata(MediaMetadataCompat.fromMediaMetadata(mediaMetadata))

val token = mediaSession.sessionToken

val mBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channelId)
    .setStyle(androidx.media.app.NotificationCompat.MediaStyle()
            .setMediaSession(token))
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you have code sample how to get `SeekBar` in notification working without `ExoPlayer` specific classes like a `PlayerNotificationManager`?

Comment: @isabsent Do you mean using SeekBar to control the progress of music/sound?

Comment: Yes - control the progress of music/sound.

Comment: I have searched the API for days but still couldn't find a solution or code sample.  If you find the solution, please tell me how.

Comment: @GreatC got the solution? I'm in the same queue along with you guys.

Comment: I have got the solution by using mediaSession.setCallback(). Code sample https://github.com/kabouzeid/Phonograph  MusicService:251 and MutilPlayer:255

Comment: This approach isn't working.

Answer (score 5):

One other way apart from what Squti has provided as a solution.

Just don't set MediaSession token in you media style notification. So as per above snippet posted by me in the query the notification would be defined like below :

```
Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this,Constant.CHANNEL_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_logo)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setLargeIcon(artwork)
            .addAction(new Notification.Action.Builder(
                    Icon.createWithResource(getApplicationContext(),playPauseResourceId),
                    "Play/Pause",
                    playPausePendingIntent).build())
            .addAction(new Notification.Action.Builder(
                    Icon.createWithResource(getApplicationContext(),R.drawable.exo_icon_stop),
                    "Play/Pause",
                    stopPendingIntent).build())
            .setStyle(new Notification.MediaStyle().setShowActionsInCompactView(0))
            .setSubText(subText)
            .setContentIntent(pendingActivityIntent)
            .setVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
            .build();
```

Just remove `.setMediaSession(mediaSession.getSessionToken())` from below :

> .setStyle(new Notification.MediaStyle().setShowActionsInCompactView(0).setMediaSession(mediaSession.getSessionToken()))

Not using or assigning the token to notification would mean that you wont have the controls you need to control your media service, also you loose feature like automatic setting of color(color temperature auto detected from album-art) on your notification and would need to write custom indents for controlling the player.

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove

```
    .setMediaSessionToken(mediaSession.getSessionToken());
```

in fact that let u show the seek bar on notification .

Comment: thanks for the answer but this approach is already suggested below