# media3 mediaSessionService remove seekbar from notification

Tags: android, exoplayer, android-media3

Im using MediaSessionService to play streaming audio in the background.
the notification shows but it has a seekbar which I want to remove.

[Disable or hide seekbar in MediaStyle notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59443133/disable-or-hide-seekbar-in-mediastyle-notifications)
this post says to add `putLong(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_DURATION, -1L)`
which i cant do because there is no "putLong" on the Media3 MediaMetadata

```
    val builder = MediaMetadata.Builder().apply {
                setStation (args.name)
                setDisplayTitle(args.name)
                setSubtitle(getString(R.string.radio_notification_description, args.name))
                setArtworkUri(args.logoUrl?.toUri())
                setIsBrowsable(false)
            }

            val media = MediaItem.Builder().setMediaId(url).setMediaMetadata(builder.build()).build()
            controller.setMediaItem(media)
            controller.prepare()
            controller.play()
```

I've also created this but I'm not sure how to actually remove it from here.

```
@UnstableApi
class CustomMediaNotificationProvider(private val context: Context) : MediaNotification.Provider {

    override fun createNotification(
        mediaSession: MediaSession,
        customLayout: ImmutableList<CommandButton>,
        actionFactory: MediaNotification.ActionFactory,
        onNotificationChangedCallback: MediaNotification.Provider.Callback
    ): MediaNotification {

//        val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, defaultMediaNotification.notification).build()
//        return  MediaNotification(defaultMediaNotification.notificationId,notification)

        val defaultMediaNotificationProvider = DefaultMediaNotificationProvider.Builder(context)
        return defaultMediaNotificationProvider.build().createNotification(mediaSession, customLayout, actionFactory, onNotificationChangedCallback)
    }

    override fun handleCustomCommand(
        session: MediaSession,
        action: String,
        extras: Bundle
    ): Boolean {
        return true
    }
}
```

or here:

```
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    override fun onUpdateNotification(session: MediaSession, startInForegroundRequired: Boolean) {
        super.onUpdateNotification(session, startInForegroundRequired)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a ForwardingPlayer as your underlying Player and override getDuration as follows to disable seekbar in mediastyle notification.

```
object: ForwardingPlayer(exoPlayer) {
    override fun getDuration(): Long {
        return C.TIME_UNSET
    }
}
```